# Tablesorter sort clicking link outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am sorting my [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) table successfully from a link [outside the table](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-trigger-sort.html), using **`var sorting = [[2,"n"]];`**. Clicking that link does sort the table the opposite way (from ASC to DESC, for example).

How can I sort the table by the 3rd column ascending, without losing the ability to sort in the opposite direction by clicking the link again? **`var sorting = [[2,"a"]];`** does sort the table ascending, but I cannot click that link again to sort in the opposite direction!

Thanks for your help!

These are my lines:

```
$("#trigger-tg").click(function() { 
    // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero 
    var sorting = [[2,"n"]]; 
    // sort on the first column 
    $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
    // return false to stop default link action 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The tablesorter link in your question is pointing to the original tablesorter, but the code links and example are from my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which does include the ability to pass an "n" to sort the column in the "next" direction.

The code example you shared does work - [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9831/).

```
$(function() {

  var $table = $("table");
  $table.tablesorter();

  $("#trigger-tg").click(function() {
    $table.trigger("sorton", [[[2, "n"]]]);
    return false;
  });

});
```

Here is the documentation page showing all possible settings - https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-trigger-sort.html

If you *must* use the original tablesorter, try the code from [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/109/).

---

Update: To notify the user that additional clicks will change the sort, try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9835/))

HTML

```
<p>Sort Animals column from <a id="trigger-tg" href="#">A-Z</a>.</p>
```

Script

```
$(function() {

  var $table = $("table"),
    targetColumn = 2;
  $table
    .on("sortEnd", function() {
      var c = this.config;
      if (c.sortList[0][0] === targetColumn) {
        $("#trigger-tg").text(c.sortList[0][1] === 0 ? "Z-A" : "A-Z");
      }
    })
    .tablesorter();

  $("#trigger-tg").click(function() {
    $table.trigger("sorton", [[[targetColumn, "n"]]]);
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I sort ASC or DESC from outside and reorder the opposite way by clicking the trigger link?

Comment: Oh, you want the user to pick asc or desc from outside?

Comment: And resort the opposite way, by clicking that link again. Yes.

Comment: Umm, how would you name the link then? A user clicking on an "asc" link would expect the table to sort in that direction, unless you want to update the link text?

Comment: I want to sort the table ASC by clicking a link, and by clicking again sort it the opposite way (DESC)... Didn‘t get that to work.

Comment: That's what the demo I shared does... keep clicking the link and the sort direction will switch.

Comment: But it does not on my text link. It sorts only once. Clicking that link again has no effect.

Comment: Wha? Are you referring to this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9831/

Comment: Exactly, but how can this be sorted desc, from Z to A and atvthe same time be clicked again for sorting the other way, from A to Z?

Comment: The demo *is* working for me. I updated it to change the link text to make it more obvious - http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9835/ (code added to the answer). If it *still* isn't working, please make sure you're using the forked version of tablesorter, and the latest version.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help an time! Your jsfiddle looks good and is working, but I still have problems to sort DESC with the first click. I do always get the table sorted from A to Z :(

Comment: Use the [`sortInitialOrder` setting](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortinitialorder) to change the initial order.